# Check for whole number in case statement

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-modeler

In an elevation file I want to find all the 5m contours and mark a column up as major. This has to be done in QGIS in the field calculator or modeler.

I want to do something like the following based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002217/how-do-you-check-whether-a-number-is-divisible-by-another-number-python)

```
CASE WHEN "elevation" %% 5 THEN 'major'
 WHEN "elevation" %% 1 THEN "moderate"
 ELSE "Minor"
 END
```

But this doesn't work -

> Parser Error: syntax error, unexpected MOD
>
> Eval Error: No root node! Parsing failed?

Ideally I want to run it as part of the following (which works but level 50 includes 1m and 5m contours)

```
CASE WHEN  "contour_level" = 48 THEN 'minor'
 WHEN  "contour_level" = 49 THEN 'minor'
 WHEN  "contour_level" = 50 THEN 'moderate'
 ELSE 'Check'
 END
```

Comment: You've tagged "python" in this question, but your code looks nothing like python.

Comment: If it does get through to Python then the modulus operator is `%` rather than `%%`.

Comment: @Fezter -it is python within qgis modeler

Comment: @PolyGeo I tried with % as well, both give the same error.

Comment: I'll leave this one to the QGIS/pyQGIS people then - [tag:pyqgis] may be a better tag to use than [tag:python].

Comment: Couple of points: a single `%` is used in the field calculator; values must be in single quotes ( ' ), field names in double quotes ( " ). Are you wanting to find only 1m and 5m contours? If so, could you not use `CASE WHEN "elevation" = 5 THEN 'major'`. Because when you use the **modulus operator**, you are finding all multiples of a certain value. So finding the modulus of 5 (assuming the remainder is 0) would print 'major' for 5m, 10m, 15m etc.

Comment: @Joseph that worked. I needed 1m and 5m intervals not just 1m and 5m lines. I ended up with [[CASE WHEN "elevation" % 1 THEN 'minor'
 WHEN "elevation" % 5 THEN 'moderate'
 ELSE 'major'
 END]] If you want to post your comment as an answer I can accept it for your status increase :-)

Comment: @GeorgeC - Awesome, glad you got it working! Thanks but I will let you post the answer :)

Comment: Please, post [your comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169951/check-for-whole-number-in-case-statement#comment253613_169951) as an answer. Is it ok to self-answer. See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer. Let me know when you post it; I will upvote. Tks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the reply from @Joseph, I found that the following worked.

I needed 1m and 5m intervals not just 1m and 5m lines. I ended up with

```
[[CASE
  WHEN "elevation" % 1 THEN 'minor'
  WHEN "elevation" % 5 THEN 'moderate'
  ELSE 'major'
END]]
```

Comment: @Joseph thanks I have added it as an answer.